# Absoluteness of $\Sigma^1_1$ sets (in transitive proper class models of ZFC)

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

$M$ is a transitive proper class model of $ZFC$.

Let $T$ be a tree on $\omega \times \omega$ and $T \in M$. We know $proj([T])$ are precisely the $\Sigma^1_1$ sets (i.e, $\Sigma^1_1$ = $\omega$-suslin). Oh and by the way we know being a tree is absolute, $\omega$ is absolute, etc.

So we want to show $(x \in proj([T]))^M \iff x \in proj([T])$

$\implies$ is pretty easy.

$\impliedby$ is what I'm looking at.

I'm aware of the result that $\Pi^1_1$ sets are $\omega_1$-suslin, and that does a lot of the heavy lifting for me. I now have a tree $U$ on $\omega \times \omega_1$ such that $proj([U]) = \omega^\omega - proj([T])$.

Is this the right way to leverage this info to prove the result:

$x \in proj[T] \rightarrow x \not \in proj[U] \rightarrow (x \not \in proj[U])^M$ (this comes from $\implies $ direction).

Now I want to say $(proj[U] = \omega^\omega - proj[T])^M$ is $(proj[U])^M = (\omega^\omega)^M -(proj[T])^M$, and since $(\omega^\omega)^M = \omega^\omega \cap M$, we get that

$(x \not \in proj[U])^M \rightarrow (x \not \in \omega^\omega - proj[T])^M \rightarrow x \not \in \omega^\omega \cap M - (proj[T])^M \rightarrow x \in (proj [T])^M \rightarrow (x \in proj[T])^M$

Thus $x \in proj[T] \rightarrow (x \in proj[T])^M$ giving us $\impliedby$ direction.

Is this the right idea? And if not, where did I go wrong?

Here's a few roadblocks I can think of:

- I made some relativization mistake in my mess of implications.
- More importantly, I'm more worried about problems of absoluteness with $\omega_1$ and trees on $\omega_1$, and $\omega_1$-suslin sets. If this is indeed a problem I think I will have to try and use the fact that $x \in proj[T] \iff T_x$ is ill founded, to get around $\omega_1$ issues.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to bring $\omega_1$, Suslinness, etc. into this. Instead, you should use the following:

> **(Mostowski absoluteness)** Suppose $M$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $P\in M$ is a partial ordering. Then $P$ is ill-founded in reality iff $P$ is ill-founded in $M$.

*Note that $M$ doesn't have to be a proper class! Similarly, Shoenfield absoluteness applies to set-sized structures as well: for Shoenfield, we merely need $M$ to be a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with $\omega_1^V$ as an element - which is more than in Mostowski, but still much less than proper classhood.*

The proof is as follows. Clearly ill-foundedness in $M$ yields ill-foundedness in reality, since "is a descending sequence" is absolute. The other direction is the nontrivial one. Suppose $M$ thinks $P$ is well-founded. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves *(and this is a good exercise)* that a partial order $Q$ is well-founded iff it admits a ranking function, that is, a function $f:Q\rightarrow\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $a\le_Qb\implies f(a)\le f(b)$. Since $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $M$ thinks $P$ is well-founded, there is in $M$ some $f$ such that $M$ thinks $f$ is a ranking function for $P$. Being a ranking function is absolute (the key point being that being an *ordinal* is absolute), and so in reality $f$ is a ranking function. But the existence of a ranking function implies well-foundedness, so $P$ is well-founded in reality.

---

By considering $T_x$, Mostowski absoluteness gives the result you want - for arbitrary transitive $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$, not just the proper class sized ones.

In fact, even *that's* overkill: all we needed from $M$ was transitivity and some very basic set theory, much less than $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - Mostowski absoluteness holds for all transitive models of $\mathsf{KP}$ + "Every set is contained in an admissible set."

Comment: Thanks! Yes this was my alternative if $\omega_1$ stuff failed (see the last two sentences). But does $\omega_1$ and suslinity and whatnot fail in the first place? It fails for some transitive set models yes, but what about transitive proper classes? 

And if not, does my proof work? 

That being said, your approach is probably the better one, and I'll try to solve it that way too.

Comment: Moreover $\omega_1$ suslinity being equivalent to $\Pi^1_1$ was one of the previous problems asked so I figured I might as well use it.